# can't find path of the module when Lazy load module with Router's resetConfig() method

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am working on an application where I need to load modules dynamically in the application, for that I have api which provide me the details (i.e routerConfig)here is data I get from api.

```
[
 {
  "path": "lazy",
  "loadChildren": "app/lazy-module/lazy.module#LazyModule",
  "data":{"name":"my lazy module"}
 } 
]
```

I use the Router's `resetConfig()` method to update my route config once I get the data from api.I append the data as `children` of main route as follow.

```
loadRoutingConfiguration(id: string) {
 this.appService.getRoutesByOrgId(id)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      let config = this.router.config;
      config[0].children = response;
      this.router.resetConfig(config);
    }
  );
}
```

Router config gets updated properly but when I try to navigate to the path `lazy` it gives me error,

```
Cannot find module 'app/lazy-module/lazy.module'
```

Here `app/lazy-module/lazy.module` is the path where my Module file is defined but the application can't find the module. What am I doing wrong?
 What path I should use to load the module. I found one plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/FDaiDvklexT68BTaNqvE?p=preview where the module is loading fine but it's not working for me.I need help to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you recreate your code's misbehavior in a plnkr